# name-based virtual hosting in Apache

Tags: apache, redmine

I'd like to set up name-based virtual hosting in Apache, but I don't have DNS name (local private network). Thus I want to get something like that:

```
http://192.168.0.1/wiki - First virtual host - wiki.
http://192.168.0.1/redmine - Second virtual host - redmine.
```

As I suggest I can be achievable by using **ServerName** option in  section of both vhosts. But in Apache documentation has no mention that I can use for FQDN IP-addr. Is it possible? How can I reach my wishes?
P.S.: I want to share my sites on the same subnet only. Thus any who can ping me can enter `http://my_ip/wiki` and get wiki, `http://my_ip/redmine` and get redmine.

Comment: -1 this is a valid question on ServerFault.com, but is probably off-topic for SO. This isn't about programmming.

Comment: @Faiz I agree with you but also as a developer you may need to setup such an environment for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple websites on localhost if you enter them in your local `hosts` file:

It is under Windows in `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`. In Linux and Unix systems typically in `\etc\`.

The format is very simple hostname a spacer and the ip address:

```
127.0.80.1  phpmyadmin.local
127.0.80.2  joomla.local
127.0.80.3  drupal.local
```

If you want to access that domains via network you need access to a DNS server. Depending on your router (a fritzbox will block that) you could also use [dyndns](http://dyndns.org), but you must know that this will only work in your local network.

In case of usage a DNS server need to use the local network ip like `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: Yeah, I want to access these vhosts by IP via network (the same subnet), without using domain names.

Comment: You could also set multiple ip addresses to your computer.

Comment: I can ask one static IP from admins (now get IP by dhcp), bot hope to have each static IP for each service is wasteful. Is better ways to have only one static IP?

Comment: Well you can choose to use multiple ips or multiple hostnames (or DNS entries). There are no other options.